# SQL Server stored procedure works but failes while running job

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-agent

I have a problem with my stored procedure in SQL Server 2017 Developer. It gets file's modification date using `xp_cmdshell`, returns `varchar` into temp table and trying to convert this to date. The stored procedure is working when I execute it in SSMS manually, but fails when I put it into a job step.

Error from Job History:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. [SQLSTATE 22007] (Error 241)

I have marked the fragment of code that fails (when I tried to execute SP in job without this, it executed successfully).

When I execute only the "problem" code, it's working fine and returns such data:

Code:

```
select top(1) cast(left(mdate,20) as date) data_ 
from t_lomag_temp_table
```

Results:

```
2018-03-14
```

Code for stored procedure:

```
declare @lomag_bak_file_source nvarchar(400) = /*source folder*/
declare @restore_status int
declare @bak_list as table (id int identity
                          , plik varchar(200)
                          , data_bak date)
declare @baza_nazwa varchar(200)
declare @xp_cmdshell_dir varchar(1000)
declare @counter int
declare @loop_limit int
declare @bak_files_status int

set @restore_status = 0
set @bak_files_status = 0
set @counter = 1
;

truncate table t_lomag_temp_table
;

insert into @bak_list
    select concat(dl.baza,'_db.bak'), null
    from t_lomag_database_list dl
;

select @loop_limit = max(id) from @bak_list

while @counter <= @loop_limit
begin
    select @baza_nazwa = bl.plik 
    from @bak_list bl 
    where bl.id = @counter

    set @xp_cmdshell_dir = concat('dir ',@lomag_bak_file_source,@baza_nazwa)

    insert t_lomag_temp_table 
        exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @xp_cmdshell_dir

    set rowcount 5 

    delete from t_lomag_temp_table 

    set rowcount 0

    /* JOB PROBLEM CODE varchar to date*/
    update @bak_list 
    set data_bak = x.data_ 
    from (select top(1) cast(left(mdate, 20) as date) data_
          from t_lomag_temp_table) x
    where @baza_nazwa = plik

    set @counter = @counter + 1
end
;

begin transaction

delete from logistyka.dbo.t_lomag_restore_dates

commit transaction
;

begin transaction
    insert into logistyka.dbo.t_lomag_restore_dates
        select 
            plik, data_bak, 1, 0
        from 
            @bak_list
    ;

    select @bak_files_status = min(rd.date_status_fl)
    from logistyka.dbo.t_lomag_restore_dates rd
;

commit transaction
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad date.  You can find it using `try_convert()` or `try_cast()`:

```
select mdate
from t_lomag_temp_table
where try_convert(date, left(mdate, 20)) is null;
```

Your code succeeds because it is -- presumably -- easy to find valid dates in the table.  The stored procedure fails because it looks at more of the values.

Comment: Stored procedure works when I run it using exec procedure. It fails only when it is executed by job. I changed the code and now it leaves only 1 row in table:

    "16.03.2018  00:05       129 410 560 filename.bak"

Then I use cast(left(row,10) as date) and it returns:
   "2018-03-11"
I try tu update table with this value and in
    "exec procedure"
it works.
When I start job, it fails with the same error as before.

Comment: Well, I left the date as varchar and I use this type of date in procedure. It's "sql heresy" but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks and giggles run this and see if any values that cannot be converted to a date (and are throwing the error) are returned.  If so, then figure out how to handle these values gracefully, either by running an UPDATE statement to make them date-convertable, or adding a WHERE clause to exclude them from your query.

SELECT mdate
FROM t_lomag_temp_table
WHERE ISDATE(left(mdate,20))= 0